# What kinds of CMTime are invalid?

Tags: ios, cmtime, core-media

kCMTimeInvalid is invalid CMTime, but based on Apple document, there are more invalid CMTime, what are they?
What does CMTime "invalid" means? It's overflow, uninitiated or anything else?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/kcmtimeinvalid

> All fields are 0, so you can calloc or fill with 0's to make lots of them. Do not test against this using (time == kCMTimeInvalid), there are many CMTimes other than this that are also invalid. Use CMTIME_IS_INVALID(time) instead.

---

I found some cases when CMTime is invalid:

- When flags(CMTimeFlags) kCMTimeFlags_Valid not set.

  > kCMTimeFlags_Valid Must be set, or the CMTime is considered invalid.
- Some operations of CMTimeAdd

> +infinity + +infinity == +infinity
>
> -infinity + -infinity == -infinity
>
> +infinity + -infinity == invalid
>
> -infinity + +infinity == invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are five possible states:

1. +Infinity: This is similar to Float.Infinity. This is a valid value, just greater than any finite number. How might you use it? For example, imagine an API that gives you information about a time range within a video, identified by two CMTimes. You might invoke it with (-Infinity, +Infinity) to ask for information about the entire video.
2. -Infinity: This is again similar to -Float.Infinity.
3. Indefinite: This is similar to Float.NaN, as I understand. Use this when you don't know what value to use, like the duration of a live stream, as Apple [suggests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtime/1400777-indefinite). It wouldn't be right to use infinity, for example, since a live stream doesn't go on for forever. It has a finite duration; we just don't know it yet.
4. Invalid: This is a CMTime structure that doesn't obey the rules of CMTime. I assume that means things like a zero or negative denominator. Since CMTime is a C struct, it's not encapsulated, so someone can create one with invalid values like this. C structs can't have initialisers that throw an exception or return nil.
5. Numeric: This is the normal case of a finite value. Use [CMTIME_IS_NUMERIC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489401-cmtime_is_numeric) to check for this. It returns false for all the weird cases above.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you posted, it says:

> Use CMTIME_IS_INVALID(time) instead.

From `CMTime.h`, it looks like `CMTIME_IS_INVALID` is defined as:

```
#define CMTIME_IS_INVALID(time) (! CMTIME_IS_VALID(time))
```

And `CMTIME_IS_VALID` is defined as:

```
#define CMTIME_IS_VALID(time) ((Boolean)(((time).flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid) != 0))
```

So it looks like the only thing that determines if a `CMTime` is valid or not is whether the `kCMTimeFlags_Valid` flag is set.